# VBSCRIPT Outlook how to select items from within a search result window

Tags: vbscript, outlook

Dim selItems  As Selection    ' A collection of Outlook item objects in a folder
Set selItems = ActiveExplorer.Selection

This code will not work if I select one or more items from within a search results window. For example I am in outlook viewing my emails. I filter by from: or To: or some date or keyword or file type and then when I select or highlight one or more email items the code above does not detect the items.

Answer (score 0):

I have just checked this out in my Outlook 2013. The [Selection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861267(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Explorer class returns the correct results all the time (even in case of search folders).

Comment: Sorry, yes from with a "search folder" it works; but not from within the main search (not using search folders). Else is there a way I can search from within a "search folder" for specific document types (pdf, doc, etc)?